# How can we import externally created Key-pair in Hyperledger Indy wallet?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I have created ED25519 key pair externally, now I want to use it for my DID based operation, for that, I want to import that keys into my wallet! How can I do that?
PS: It is the indy-SDK wallet.

Comment: I dont think this is possible by design as this could compromise security of generated keypairs inside indy. Image that during process of transmitting keys to indy wallet somebody will get that info, you can than said that indy is not secure - but this would not be indy fault at all. Therefore creators do not allow you to export/import private keys by design.

Comment: but that is completely not scalable, or we cannot  even integrate it with existing solutions. Let's say I have a system in which user have their keypairs, and I like the concept of Indy and I thought to integrate my solution with Indy and onboard users to network, that will not going to work! Lets not consider the case of stealing the keys because that is totally depends on how I transmit and store the keys.

Comment: there is another option when creating the did you can use the seed https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/95595e4922fd462c5c672b1f7c0334062d2d76f1/wrappers/ios/libindy-pod/Indy/Wrapper/IndyDid.h#L27  so if you know what seed was used you can re-create the same did - which is basically first 16 bytes of the public key. that way you can some-how import , otherwise i dont see more options - but i could be wrong

Comment: btw what about providing your public key as a did with cid=true? that way you clients can recognize each other and than you can also use indy with all featues?

Comment: @0xSHA1001 did you able to find a solution for this?